# PDOException with mysql driver in Laravel 4.1 when running migrate:install on Uniform WAMP server

Tags: php, database, laravel-4, database-migration

I have read all relative posts but i cant get rid of my issue:

Environment:

-Laptop Win8.1 running Uniserver for local development
-MySql on port 3306
-Laravel 4.1.27

On a fresh laravel project i run

```
php artisan migrate:install
```

and i get PDOException error.

my database.php config file as follows:

```
'default' => 'mysql',

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Database Connections
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here are each of the database connections setup for your application.
    | Of course, examples of configuring each database platform that is
    | supported by Laravel is shown below to make development simple.
    |
    |
    | All database work in Laravel is done through the PHP PDO facilities
    | so make sure you have the driver for your particular database of
    | choice installed on your machine before you begin development.
    |
    */

    'connections' => array(

        'sqlite' => array(
            'driver'   => 'sqlite',
            'database' => __DIR__.'/../database/production.sqlite',
            'prefix'   => '',
        ),

        'mysql' => array(
            'driver'    => 'mysql',
            'host'      => 'localhost',
            'database'  => 'afz',
            'username'  => 'afz',
            'password'  => 'xxxxxxxx',
            'charset'   => 'utf8',
            'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
            'prefix'    => '',
        ),

        'pgsql' => array(
            'driver'   => 'pgsql',
            'host'     => 'localhost',
            'database' => 'database',
            'username' => 'root',
            'password' => '',
            'charset'  => 'utf8',
            'prefix'   => '',
            'schema'   => 'public',
        ),

        'sqlsrv' => array(
            'driver'   => 'sqlsrv',
            'host'     => 'localhost',
            'database' => 'database',
            'username' => 'root',
            'password' => '',
            'prefix'   => '',
        ),

    ),
```

Data base collation is the same as in the configuration.

PDO seems installed in phpinfo.

Cannot figure out what could go wrong....

the database access works within a controller, but i get error when i try to use migrations...

Another application that runs ok has the same problem so i suppose that it has to do with php setup, but what?

Info:

screenshot of command output

LINK: [PHOTO](http://s20.postimg.org/6e6qzwii5/Snap2.jpg)

[image: migrate:install output]

Comment: What's the error message? Please show us the output of the PDOException + the debug trace.

Answer (score 3):

You get the famous "could not find driver" exception, check in you'r PHP.ini if 
pdo_mysql is enabled

first, just insert phpinfo(); and check in PDO drivers section if mySQL is enabled.

Comment: I write it also in my post. They ARE installed and i can see them in phpinfo. Also applications run ok accessing the database...

Comment: Can you check if the  PATH php version match with the phpinfo version of php ?

Comment: I found it!!!! i will ansewr my question or update my first post. Uniform Server (WAMP) has a SEPARATE php.oini file named php-cli.ini

Comment: This one is very tricky, i think php_cli.ini is specific to windows8

Comment: Nope, it must be specific to uniform WAMP server...its being used when you call php from commandline...

Answer (score 3):

The issue had to do with Uniform Server's (WAMP) setup php.ini file

Uniform Server has a SEPARATE file for command line php commands.

The name is php-cli.ini

I added there the following two lines and everything was ok:

```
extension=php_pdo_mysql.dll
extension=php_mbstring.dll
```